# How to insert the 2D Matrix in to the nested HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public class Arc 
{
   String startPoint;
   String endPoint;
   int distance;

   Arc(String startPoint,String endPoint,int distance)
   {
       this.startPoint=startPoint;
       this.endPoint=endPoint;
       this.distance=distance;
   }
   public String getStartPoint()
   {
    return startPoint;   
   }
   public String getEndPoint()
   {
       return endPoint;
   }
   public int getDistance()
   {
       return distance;
   }
}


public class ArcCollections 
{           
    private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> outMap = new  HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>>();
private HashMap<String, Integer> inMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    public void addArc(Arc arc)
    {
        String st = arc.getStartPoint();
    String end = arc.getEndPoint();
    int dist = arc.getDistance();

    inMap.put(end, dist);
    outMap.put(st,inMap);
    }       
}
```

The sample input is something like: (i.e) `{source,{destination,distance}}`

How do i insert these values in the specified map structure? Because at the time of debugging the `inMap` yields only `null` value

The values are read from excel and passed through the object from main function as follows:

```
tmpArc = new Arc(tempFromCity,tempToCity,dist);
```

Comment: Are you sure the values are read correctly?

Comment: Also can you show your main function please.

Comment: I don't see how inMap could be null here.  Something must be setting it null because it's initialized in the declaration. Try declaring it final to see if anything breaks.